# Telegram API, SendMessage with ftp URL without http://

Tags: telegram

I tried to send a message to a bot with an FTP URL.

```
curl -s -k "https://api.telegram.org/bot123456778:Token/sendMessage" -d text="<strong>... Video fertig</strong> ftp://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/$Dateiname.avi" -d chat_id=123456789 -d parse_mode="HTML"
```

Unfortunately, Telegram always prefixes http:// (see pictures)

Is there a way without `disable_web_page_preview` to give the FTP URL correct again? [Telegram Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUtWq.png)

Answer (score 0):

We were able to narrow the issue. It seems to be exclusively in android apps and in the web-app (web.telegram.org).

In iOS, it works as expected ...